# Reducing to exact form by integrating factor

Tags: calculus

$$(6xy)dx = (4y+9x^2)dy$$
to find out if its exact
$$M= 6xy, N =4y+9x^2 $$
$$ \frac {dM}{dy} = 6x, \frac {dN}{dx} = 18x$$
Hence its not exact. Please correct me if i did something wrong and help me to make it exact by multiplying integrating factor.

Comment: You should write the equation as $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$ so $M_y=6x$ and $N_x=-(18x)$

Comment: Thanks! is it right now?
$$ (6xy)dx - (4y+9x^2)dy = 0 $$

Comment: See [this](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/intfactor/intfactor.html).

Comment: @TPSstar: See the link glebovg attached and see the **Case 2** in it. Then follow the rest of the material.

Comment: @glebovg yep i've got it but my question was written in that form that i posted first. is it appropriate to change it to your mentioned form or if equation is not in the said form then it would obviously be non-exact?

Comment: @TPSstar I did not quite understand what you mean, but you can multiply the original equation by anything and the equality will always hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply the original equation by anything and equality will always hold. However, multiplying it by an appropriate integration factor (see [Case 2](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/intfactor/intfactor.html)) makes it exact, hence easier to solve. If you are wondering where these integration factors come from, consider
$$M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0$$
and multiply by an integration factor $u(x,y)$ to make it exact.
Note that we must have
$$\frac{{\partial (uM)}}{{\partial y}} = \frac{{\partial (uN)}}{{\partial x}} \Leftrightarrow {u_y}M + u{M_y} = {u_x}N + u{N_x}$$
for exactness. If $u = u(x)$, then
$$\frac{{du}}{{dx}} = u\frac{1}{N}\left( {{M_y} - {N_x}} \right)$$
which you know how to solve if the righthand side is a function of $x$ only. Similarly, if $u = u(y)$, then
$$\frac{{du}}{{dy}} = u\frac{1}{M}\left( {{N_x} - {M_y}} \right).$$
Again, you know how to solve this if the righthand side is a function of $y$ only.

Comment: This is what I meant. +1

Comment: Who downvoted this? This answers the question perfectly.